# Android Application Development O'reilly MJAnddroid Example Code

Tags: android, console, download, emulation

Good Afternoon...

I recently bought the book "Android Application Development" from O'reilly and 
I'm at a section where it asked me to download MJAndroid Code and import into Eclipse...

Here is the link http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596521509/

I was able to downloaded / import it but now I'm stuck...

Here is what it saids...
"You can install the file into the emulator by simply starting the emulator from a terminal window

$emulator

$adb install MJAndroid-1.0.0apk

Now I'm running Windows and I'm guessing it wants me to run in dos but where do I point it to so I can install it correctly.

When I try running it I get the following error....

"Your project contains errors please fix them before running your application"

Console Error 
"[2010-02-14 12:40:02 - MJAndroid]Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one."

I hope I explained myself correctly....

Thanks again

Junior Bisono
Future Android Developer......

Answer (score 1):

1) To install the APK from the zip file you need an **AVD** (emulator) supporting Google APIs, verify that.

2) Set a target for your project (i.e.: Google APIs 1.5) right clicking on your project folder, then *Properties -> Android -> Project Build Target*.

Comment: [ Thanks For You Response ]


I tried that I did exactly what you put down.... and I get the same error message.. 

"Your project contains errors please fix them before running your application" 

I made sure that I created some AVD´supporting the GOOGLE API 1.5 as a matter of fact I tried created AVD available for every version. 

Did you try downloading the source from the link above and try to run it...

examples.oreilly.com/9780596521509 See if you can run in a emulator and see if that works if so please let me know.




Thanks.
 
Junior Bisono

Comment: The APK works on the emulator as described in 1).
You can rebuild your project fixing the target as described in 2).

Answer (score 0):

The message about the errors is because the MJAndroid project that you are using has problems - one of them is that it most likely doesn't have a 'default.properties' file. This file is supposed to direct it to the android API version.